# Android opengl es 2.0 software rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-build

i'm using android 4.1.2 (linaro) at a vexpress platform. Since there is no hardware GPU i'm wondering if it's possible to use the software renderer for opengl es 2.0 support.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Yoy don't need a GPU to use OpenGL. It is supported and compatible on all graphics hardware.

Comment: Ok, but the system says there is no suitable OpenGLES2.0 config. So the question is how to configure the android image build to use the android software rendering lib which is writing into a framebuffer device.